# C# compile numerical expression

Tags: c#, compilation

Assume I allow the user to input a arbitrary numerical expression that allows usage of the explicit set of functions and predefined variables.

Interpreting this is pretty straight forward but what if performance is a critical factor?

I need a way to compile (in runtime) a string with a expression into something that can be executed 20K times with different values on the variables.

Comment: How the original expression is defined? I.e. is it a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So really you want to parse the string into (eventually) a typed delegate.

One option, then it to parse the string into an `Expression`, which you can then compile to a lambda. This is quite complex, but I have some code that will do much of this - but there may be existing parsers that already do the job in full.

As a trivial `Expression` example:

```
    var x = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "x");
    var y = Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "y");
    var body = Expression.Multiply(x, y);
    var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<double, double,double>>(body, x, y).Compile();

    double z = func(123.45, 678.90);
```

The problem is the rest of the parsing code ;-p

I wrote a `string` to `Expression` parser last week, but it is more code than I'd normally post here... over 300 lines (not including recognition of bespoke external functions, or named arguments (it currently uses anonymous "?" place-holders)).

but if (as you say) interpreting is easy, then perhaps use similar code to write an `Expression` that you can compile?

Comment: @Mehrdad - I have most of the code "to hand", I'm just not sure this is the best dumping ground... existing parsers probably exist too. And the OP states "Interpreting this is pretty straight forward" so this might not be unfamiliar territory anyway.

Comment: Yeah, surely this is the better way. The JScript way is vulnerable to dangerous things such as JS injection.

Comment: This looks as the solution I'm after, but what about performance? (Parsing isn't easy, but it's a common problem that is't easy to find example source code for, didn't mean to trivialize it :)

Comment: Once you have it compiled to a delegate, the performance will be very, very fast. Essentially, as though had had written a single C# method to do "x + y * z/sin(x)" etc

Comment: Get back to me if you need help with the parser... I'm fairly easy to track down

Answer (score 2):

Linq Samples by Microsoft already contain implementation of extensible Linq parser.

```
sealed class Order
{
  public double SubTotal { get; set; }
  public double Shipping { get; set; }
}
static void Main()
{
  var calculateTotal = DynamicExpression
    .ParseLambda<Order, double>("SubTotal*@0+Shipping", 0.12)
    .Compile();

  var order = new Order
  {
    SubTotal = 124.99,
    Shipping = 7.99
  };
  Console.WriteLine(calculateTotal(order));
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You can check out the [DbLinq project](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/) for sources or this post for more details: [Dynamic Linq and Expression Parsing in .NET as a hint of C# compiler extensibility](http://rabdullin.com/journal/2008/12/7/dynamic-linq-and-expression-parsing-in-net-as-a-hint-of-c-co.html)

Answer (score 1):

In C# 4.0, it'll become very easy and straightforward. However, before C# 4.0, I suggest you use `Microsoft.JScript` libraries to accomplish it.

This is all you want: http://www.odetocode.com/Articles/80.aspx